# initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle) not called

Tags: ios, objective-c

A weird thing just happend, i trying to build my custom tablecell but my initWithStyle is not called.

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
```

**My Tablecell looks normal:**

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        NSLog(@"xx1111");
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

**How i'm trying to load the Customcell nib:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *TFDCustomCell = @"TFDCell";
    TFDCell *cell = (TFDCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:TFDCustomCell];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TFDCell"
                                                     owner:self options:nil];
        for (id oneObject in nib) if ([oneObject isKindOfClass:[TFDCell class]])
            cell = (TFDCell *)oneObject;
    }

return cell;

}
```

But the `NSLog(@"xx1111");` doenst appear in my logs. When i place a NSLog in 'setSelected' it works 'fine'

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The solution was simple

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    NSLog(@"initWithCoder");

    self = [super initWithCoder: aDecoder];
    if (self)
    {

    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

As I know if you load your view (in current case cell) from nib `initWithStyle:` method wont be called. Overload `awakeFromNib:` method instead to make custom initialization.

Comment: You can also override `initWithCoder`, which is called when objects are unarchived from a nib file.

Answer (score 0):

You're not initializing the table's cells with **initWithStyle** so **initWithStyle** of your custom cell won't be fired. But **awakeFromNib** will be called for your initialization call of  **dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier**.

Comment: 'if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TFDCell"
                                                     owner:self options:nil];
        for (id oneObject in nib) if ([oneObject isKindOfClass:[TFDCell class]])
            cell = (TFDCell *)oneObject;
    }' 
can be skipped for iOS 6 and later and **dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier** would invoke **awakeFromNib**. So, @Paul, this seems a bit extra on top of Rost's explanation. Also, I cannot add comment against Rost cause of fewer points.

Comment: so you should make it clear, that for newer versions (now it is ios8), you can do another way, and put it in your answer, to help people understand why it is useful two years after.